# Search for a street and display the marker on google maps. Marker drifting away

Tags: android, google-maps

I coded the tutorial to search for an address in google maps.
Unfortunately the marker doesn't stick at the place when I'm zomming out.
It seems that the marker ist drifting away.

```
class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {

    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
    boolean shadow, long when) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

        // translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

        // add the red marker
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.marker_red);            
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-32, null);         
        return true;
    }
}
```

I think it comes from translating the GeoPoint into screen pixels
Here's the code from the onClick Event of the search button:

```
    this.searchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            followMe = false;

            String temp = searchBar.getText().toString();
            List<Address> addresses = null;
            try {
                addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(temp,5);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (addresses != null) {
                p = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6),
                        (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));

                mapController.animateTo(p);
                mapController.setZoom(19);

                MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
                mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                mapOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

                mapView.postInvalidate();
                //searchBar.setText("");
            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        GMapsSubActivity.this);
                adb.setTitle("Google Map");
                adb.setMessage("Please Provide the Proper Place");
                adb.setPositiveButton("Close", null);
                adb.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

searchbar is an editText and followMe is not relevant.
I want the marker to stick at the place that I sought for when I'm zooming out.

Images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJuix.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/dFqIs.jpg

Comment: is internet turned on or off when this happens ?

Comment: have you confirmed that the geopoint coordinations dont change ?

Comment: no, will do it soon! added same pictures of the problem.

Comment: solved it! I wrote canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x - (bmp.getWidth() / 2), screenPts.y - bmp.getHeight(), new Paint()); instead of canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-32, null);

Comment: yes, the good old "magic numbers" problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understand your code correctly ... but as a general answer: you can't use latitude and longitude values directly when spreading a position over several tiles. That's because earth is a sphere (somehow) and you get some inaccuracies when using linear map tiles and zooming in/out with the same linear translation value.

There are several algorithms out there that incorporate this spherical distortion, I personally have "stolen" some useful code in GeoUtils class from http://libwlocate.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=libwlocate/libwlocate;a=tree;f=master/android/LocDemo/src/com/vwp/libwlocate/map;h=3afbc1b212a6824c557cda01ee38f3b0ee6d51ef;hb=HEAD

Comment: thats what the Projection class is for. It knows what pixel/geocoord has to be on a tile.